# How to execute `docker exec -it netvertex bash` by Java Program

Tags: java, docker

How to execute `docker exec -it netvertex bash` by Java Program.
By this i am trying to execute but not working

```
public void execute(String command) {
        try {

            System.out.println("===========>" + command);
            Channel channel1 = session.openChannel("exec");

            ((ChannelExec) channel1).setPty(true);
            ((ChannelExec) channel1).setCommand(command);
            // X Forwarding
            // channel.setXForwarding(true);

            //channel.setInputStream(System.in);
            channel1.setInputStream(null);

            //channel.setOutputStream(System.out);

            //FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream("/tmp/stderr");
            //((ChannelExec)channel).setErrStream(fos);
            ((ChannelExec) channel1).setErrStream(System.err);

            InputStream in1 = channel1.getInputStream();

            channel1.connect();

            byte[] tmp1 = new byte[1024];
            while (true) {
                while (in1.available() > 0) {
                    int i = in1.read(tmp1, 0, 1024);
                    if (i < 0) break;
                    System.out.print(new String(tmp1, 0, i));
                }
                if (channel1.isClosed()) {
                    if (in1.available() > 0) continue;
                    System.out.println("exit-status: " + channel1.getExitStatus());
                    break;
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (Exception ee) {
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
```

By above code my other Linux command are working. But docker exec it not working.
And the other option i tried

```
try {

            String host = "root@10.121.21.224";
            String passwd = "root#10";
            Terminal exec = new Terminal(pageUiUtils);
            exec.loginSSH(host, passwd);

            String[] command = {"docker", "exec", "-it", "netvertex", "bash"};
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command);
            pb.inheritIO();
            Process proc = pb.start();

            InputStream is = proc.getInputStream();
            OutputStream os = proc.getOutputStream();

            BufferedReader reader
                    = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            BufferedWriter writer
                    = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os));
            writer.write("pwd");
            writer.flush();
            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.print(line + "\n");
            }

            exec.execute("docker exec -it netvertex bash");
            pageUiUtils.pause(1000);
            exec.execute("pwd");
            //proc.waitFor();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

by above code also showing error that 
`The input device is not a TTY`

Comment: the error because you add `-it`  to the command

Comment: Generally, you don't, and you can't without trusting the program with unrestricted root-level access over the host.  It's better to write a proper API in the service you're calling into and making something like an HTTP call to it.

Comment: It might also be a good idea to use the Docker API in java: https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java/wiki.

Comment: You want to open a bash inside the container to execute `pwd` or what is going to be the full scale vision?!